# Python - how to get add a counter inside a IF condition to add track the number of times something has occured

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, binance

I am new to python and learning it in bits and peices from internet. I have been tring to get a volume monitor for binance volumes.

```py
for x in range(len(name)):
    # Code to get the data into panda dataframes for each token in name[] 
    hrlyvol = res1["volume"].iloc[0]
    min_2vol = res1["volume"].iloc[-1]
    actvol = hrlyvol - min_2vol
    voldiff = hrlyvol/actvol
    volch = voldiff-1
    op_price = res1["open"].iloc[0]
    cl_price = res1["close"].iloc[-1]
    price_change = (cl_price-op_price)/op_price
    
    if volch > 0.05 or price_change > 0.02:
    
        print("Volume is up by {:.0%} and Price has changed by {:.0%} in {}".format(
            volch, price_change, name[x]))
        time.sleep(3)
```

i tried adding `i = i+1` but it then adds for all the tokens that  satisfy this rule.
what i want is for each token to have a separate counter since not all tokens would satisfy the condition.
lets say `xyz` and `abc`  met the condition then token should be `xyz = 1` `abc = 1`
then if in the next iteration only `xyz` met the condition then `xyz = 2` `abc = 1`
and so on.

Comment: can't you just increment your counter in an if statement? it seems like you already have an example of this...

Comment: i think you could define `xyz` `abc` equal to `1` before for loop and update values inside conditional by:

`xyz, abc = 1, 1
for x in range(len(name)):
    if volch > 0.05 or price_change > 0.02:
        xyz=1. abc=1

    # update values
    xyz+=1
    abc+=1`

Comment: thanks will try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: wouldnt that change theinitial list where xyz is stored to 1 and then mess up the whole loop?

Comment: i used a list to capture the tokens inside the conditional statement and then used the python counter() to count the number of occurances. will have to clear the list once it gets big enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the example of odd number or even number to showcase the condition

```
i=0
j=0
for n in range(100):
    i = i+1 if n%2 == 0 else i+0
    j = j+1 if n%2 == 1 else j+0
```

Comment: how do i add that to the specific token. there are hundreds of them in name[]

Comment: @PreneshKp, could you elaborate more what exactly you are trying to achieve? It's not so clear from your description what you are looking after.